# Properly populate an email using only HTML

Tags: html, forms

For an assignment, I need to put a `form` in my webpage, and have the form populate an email for the user to send.

I wrote up this after searching around:

```
<form enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="mailto:[My Email Here]">
    <input type="text" name="subject" value="Subject" />
    <input type="text" name="body" value="Body" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Which, as I expected opens my mail client and populates an email for me. The problem is, the way it's populated is quite ugly and unintuitive. The subject line is left blank, and the body is filled with:

```
subject=Subject

body=Body

submit=Submit

(4 lines of white-space)
```

Ideally, I'd like the "subject" to end up in the subject, the "body" field to be the only thing that ends up in the body, and the "submit" to not appear to the user at all.

Is this possible?

I am only allowed to use HTML at this point. (Solely HTML. No inline scripting allowed).

Comment: Can you use inline javascript?

Comment: @gfullam No, I am completely restricted to HTML right now.

Comment: If you are using PHP Mail to sent the emails out, you will have to define the layout of the sent email on the server side scripting.

Comment: @DannyGibas I am **completely** restricted to HTML.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I am just explaining that you cant define how the sent email appears with HTML alone. You need to be able to define the HTML layout, populate the fields, and then send it. This has to be done on the server.

Comment: It can be done using the browser's native handling of forms and mailto links. It's not a robust or conventional pattern, but it is possible. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GET instead of POST

Change the form's method from `POST` to `GET`. Using the `GET` method will append the key/value pairs from the `input` fields as a query string on the `mailto:` link in the `action` attribute. This creates a URL that email clients understand how to parse:

`mailto:{TARGET EMAIL ADDRESS}?subject=Subject&body=Body`

```html
<form enctype="text/plain" method="GET" action="mailto:{TARGET EMAIL ADRESS}">
    <input type="text" name="subject" value="Subject"/>
    <input type="text" name="body" value="Body"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I'm looking for. The only problem now is that spaces are replaced by `+`s. Can that be fixed by altering the encoding type?

Comment: Nvm, doesn't seem to be possible by changing encoding. Am I right in that the `+`s are mandatory? Regardless, this answers my question, so thank you.

Comment: And the code snippet doesn't work for some reason. SO might be blocking something.

Comment: Yes, `enctype` only affects `POST`. It is ignored when using `GET`. So you're kind of stuck. This is really where JavaScript comes into play. If you could even use basic inline JS, you could properly encode the values so that `%20` is used instead of `+`, which would translate back into spaces in your email client.

Comment: Thank you. I guess for the time being I'll stick to my original code since the "+"s make it quite difficult to read, but down the road when I can use JS, I'll likely switch. Thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: Because this exercise is for an assignment, I am going to assume that you were expected to discover these caveats. Your instructor may use your discoveries as a springboard into a conversation about `GET` vs `POST`, form encoding, and using JavaScript for validation.

Comment: It's online, self directed learning, so that's not likely unless I make a post on the message board. That's not a bad idea though, since I'm marked on my discussion participation as well.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're being proactive. Good luck with your curriculum.

Answer (score -1):

mailto forms will always adds all the fields to mail body. javascript can do trick for you. are you allowed to use Javascript ..?

May be this will work for you

```
<html>

<form onsubmit="window.location='mailto:me@domain.com?subject='+myform.subject.value + '&body='+myform.comments.value" name="myform"  method="post">

<input name="subject"  value="Commencement Form" />
<input name="comments"  value="my body" />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</from>
</html>
```

Comment: It's been stated that I am completely restricted to HTML.